# Why did the browser never update itself from zombie service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

In this brillant talk [Alexander Pope: ServiceWorkers Outbreak: index-sw-9a4c43b4b47781ca619eaaf5ac1db.js | JSConf EU 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPP9ew4Co0M):
The presenter has a situation where a broken service worker gets installed, and its stuck in the broken state. The presenter tries a kill switch and an empty service worker to remedey it, but there are still some browsers permantely infected. I am trying to understand why it happened, and not do a similar thing.

Here is his code (from 22m:57s):

```js
function onInstall(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        install(config.version, config.assets)
            .catch((err) => {
                reportError(err);
                // Ok, you know what you're doing, Installing now....
            })
    );
}
```

It gets stuck because within the call to `install` he uses `cache.addAll()`, but long ago Chrome didnt support `cache`, so this error never bubbled up, and the browser thought it was installed correctly.

Now the browser is reponsible for fetching the `sw.js` file and checking if its byte different to the currently installed worker. The code to register the new `sw.js` file is outside of the service worker file. This means even if a service worker is broken, the browser should be able to fetch the new one, determine its different, register it, and activate it (eventually). The newer `sw.js` file could then check for the presence of `cache` API. So why are there some clients still in a broken state?